# assignment is not working in external js file

Tags: jquery

friends i have created a new js file for autocomplete. Everything is working fine except one line  " receivingAutocompleteData = data.autcompleteData;" 
right hand side value is not assigned to left hand side.

```
var ArrayAutocomplete = [];
var receivingAutocompleteData ;
function AutoComplete1(txtBoxName, idField, fieldName) {
debugger;
ArrayAutocomplete = [];

var selectedReqType = $("#" + txtBoxName).val();

$("#" + txtBoxName).unautocomplete();
$("#" + txtBoxName).val("");

$("#" + txtBoxName).val("Loading...........");
$("#" + txtBoxName).attr("disabled", true);


// var rea=  "<%= Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Request", action =   "AutoSelectionDataForRequestType"}) %>";
var rea = getURL(fieldName);
$.post(rea, {}, function (data) {
    debugger;
    receivingAutocompleteData = data.autcompleteData;
    jQuery.each(receivingAutocompleteData, function (i, val) {
        if (val.Name != "")
            ArrayAutocomplete.push(val.Name + '|' + val.ID);
    });
    ArrayAutocomplete.sort();

    //   alert(ArrayAutocomplete.length);
    //  alert(ArrayAutocomplete);
    $("#" + txtBoxName).autocomplete(ArrayAutocomplete, {

        minChars: 0,
        max: ArrayAutocomplete.length,
        autoFill: true,
        mustMatch: true,
        matchContains: false,
        multipleSeparator: ',-',
        scrollHeight: 220,

        formatItem: function (data, index, max) {
            return data[0];
        },
        formatMatch: function (data, index, max) {
            return data[0];
        }, formatResult: function (data, index, max) {
            return data[0];
        }
    }).result(function (event, data, formatted) {
        if (data)
            $("#" + idField).val(data[1]);
        else
            $("#" + idField).val('-1');
    });
    $("#" + txtBoxName).val("");
    $("#" + txtBoxName).attr("disabled", false);
    $("#" + txtBoxName).Watermark("--Select--");

    if (selectedReqType != '')
        $("#" + txtBoxName).val(selectedReqType);
   });
```

}

Comment: Impossible to say whats wrong here, as you are working with the result of a post request. Are you sure that data.autcompleteData is actually containing a value? Do you have a typo? Should it be autoCompleteData?

Comment: i have debug the application and found value in "data.autcompleteData" variable but this value is not assign into the lefthand operand.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses the content-type header to determine the type of the returned data. Since most servers don't send a `application/json` so you have to specify "json" as the data type (4th parameter of `$.post`)

You also might have a typo

I think it should be

```
data.autocompleteData
```

instead of

```
data.autcompleteData
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the `data`?

Probably you've just made a mistype in `receivingAutocompleteData = data.autcompleteData;`; the proper field name is "data.aut **o** completeData;".

Comment: data is json data which coming as a ajax response from server.as a json data i am sending the entire object